# GridView in Fragment only show images after the user change orientation

Tags: android, image, gridview, orientation, fragment

Im building a gridview with some images and the code seems ok, but when i test the app, the gridview only show the images after i rotate my smartphone and orientation changes. After this, the gridview works in any orientation.

Comment: Are you calling notifyDataSetChanged() on the Adapter after adding all the elements? Changing the orientation will cause the Activity to be recreated, and the Views to be invalidated (same effect as notifyDataSetChanged()), which could be why it works after the change and not before.

Comment: Maybe i expressed wrong. It only when i change orientation, but if i change again still works. Only in the first time i have to change orientation to make it work.

Comment: And no, im not calling this method.

Comment: My getView is called too when i press a button, or press back button.